# Basic session handling with WebAPI and RavenDB

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ravendb

Using this as a base APIController, thoughts? mostly im curious about handling savechanges in dispose, vs. the ExecuteAsync method which i've seen elsewhere...

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using Raven.Client;
using Raven.Client.Document;

public abstract class RavenDbController : ApiController
{
    private IDocumentStore _documentStore;

    public IDocumentStore Store
    {
        get { return _documentStore ?? (_documentStore = LazyDocStore.Value); }
        set { _documentStore = value; }
    }

    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        Session = Store.OpenSession();
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        using (Session)
        {
            Session.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public IDocumentSession Session { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I prefer using an action filter attribute in order to manage the life cycle of the session object on the base API controller. See the following code which demonstrate this approach:

```
public class RavenSessionManagementAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly IDocumentStore store;

    public RavenSessionManagementAttribute(IDocumentStore store)
    {
        if (store == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("store");    
        this.store = store;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var controller = actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller as AbstractApiController;
        if (controller == null)
            return;

        // Can be set explicitly in unit testing
        if (controller.RavenSession != null)
            return;

        controller.RavenSession = store.OpenSession();
        controller.RavenSession.Advanced.UseOptimisticConcurrency = true;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        var controller = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ControllerContext.Controller as AbstractApiController;
        if (controller == null)
            return;

        using (var session = controller.RavenSession)
        {
            if (session == null)
                return;

            if (actionExecutedContext.Exception != null)
            {
                session.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FilterConfig.cs:

```
public class FilterConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(HttpFilterCollection filters)
        {
            filters.Add(new RavenSessionManagementAttribute(DocumentStoreHolder.Store));
        }
    }
```

AbstractApiController.cs:

```
public abstract class AbstractApiController : ApiController
    {
        public IDocumentSession RavenSession { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: @FitzchakYitzchaki: Why would I want to use this instead of the (easier looking) approach in the question? *(Note: I'm a Web API **and** RavenDB beginner, so it's possible that I'm missing something)*

Comment: Because that this encapsulate the functionality in an attribute rather than adding it to a base controller. This keeps the base controller more clean.

Comment: Also, you may want to reference the DocumentStoreHolder that I reputedly heard Ayende made for his Racoon thing.